# Case Statement with 2 columns

Tags: sql

If Dr's name is SoinSo, then make column "Clinic Number Column" say "SO" instead of "06"

This is just a select statement not an actual change to the database.

Not sure how to code this in SQL to get this specific output.

This is the current output:

```
   Dr Name Column | Clinic Number Column
   ---------------+---------------------
   Doe              06
   SoinSo           06
   James            06
```

This is the desired Output:

```
   Dr Name Column | Clinic Number Column
   ---------------+---------------------
   Doe              06
   SoinSo           SO
   James            06
```

I've tried this, but couldn't find any documentation online about doing a CASE statement for 2 columns:

`When stf.DrName='SoInSo' then pc.ClinicNumberColumn='SO'`

Comment: share you complete SQL

Comment: CASE 
When stf.DrName='SoInSo' then pc.ClinicNumberColumn='SO' I cant put the full sql query because this is a hospital database

Comment: you donot need any two column case statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the desired output from following (not tested):

```
SELECT 
    stf.DrName
    ,CASE WHEN stf.DrName='SoInSo' THEN 'SO' ELSE pc.ClinicNumberColumn END AS "CLINIC"
FROM 
   TABLE
```